# JList putting text into specific textfields based on how many are clicked

Tags: java, swing, onclick, jpanel, jlist

I'm currently creating a soundboard application where the person is going to click one of the items in my JList and its going to set the name of the next available text field as what was just clicked then i'm going to add buttons later.

For example, if my first click is the 2nd item in the JList it will go into the first JTextfield and my second click will go into the second JTextfield.

The program will have around 100 items in the JList by the time the app is done.

Also there is a problem that when the top one and a different JList item is clicked the top one will display first. Not necessarily a problem if I can get the problem fully functional but it makes it feel a little wonky.

```
 package com.leagueoflegends.soundboard;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

import java.awt.*;

public class Soundboard implements ListSelectionListener {

static JList<Object> list;
String[] text = { "hello", "testing1", "testing2" };
Icon icon;
JLabel pictureLabel;
JPanel insidePanel;
JTextField inlineText;

JTextField field[] = new JTextField[6];

public Soundboard() {
JFrame f = new JFrame("soundboard!");

JPanel masterPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

//icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Tray.png"));
//pictureLabel = new JLabel(icon);

list = new JList<Object>(text); // data has type Object[]
list.setSelectionModel(new DefaultListSelectionModel(){
    public void setSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1){
        if(super.isSelectedIndex(index0)){
            super.removeSelectionInterval(index0,index1);
        }else{
            super.addSelectionInterval(index0,index1);
        }
    }
});
list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL_WRAP);
list.setVisibleRowCount(-1);
list.addListSelectionListener(this);

JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane(list);
listScroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
listScroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
listScroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 60));
// listScroller.setSize(new Dimension(250, 60));

JPanel smallPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 3));
// smallPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    insidePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    insidePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    field[i] = new JTextField();
    field[i].setEditable(false);
    field[i].setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    insidePanel.add(field[i], BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    smallPanel.add(insidePanel);

}

masterPanel.add(smallPanel);
masterPanel.add(pictureLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
masterPanel.add(listScroller, BorderLayout.WEST);
f.add(masterPanel);

f.pack();
f.setSize(1000, 800);
f.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 350));
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
f.setVisible(true);
}

public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
if (e.getValueIsAdjusting() == false) {
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        if (list.getSelectedIndex() == i) {
            field[0].setText(text[i]);
        }
    }
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException |     IllegalAccessException
                | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        new Soundboard();
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correct than you have to provide a custom list model to your list. You can initialize your JList with this custom list model.

The entries of your list model hold a reference to 
an appropriate textfield instance. So each time you select an entry of the list you
have access to your custom list item you can manipulate the text of the associated textfield.

The custom list model must implement the ListModel interface or extend AbstractListModel class.

There are many nice tutorials have a look here:

Swing/UsingaCustomDataModel.htm">http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240_Swing/UsingaCustomDataModel.htm

Hope it helps.